# image does not remain within div with absolute position (using css grid)

Tags: html, css, sass, css-position, css-grid

I'm trying to contain an image within `<div class="bg-image"></div>` with a header inside that div. But unfortunately the header is being affected by the opacity from `class="bg-image"`

I added `position:absolute;` to `class="bg-image"` this way I can move my header from within the div to the outside and the header will overlap the image. But my site went from [How it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMOUx.jpg) to [How it's not suppose to look](https://imgur.com/a/oOQIm)

My guess is since I'm using CSS Grid the width set to 100% is someway messing it up. My question is how can I contain the image within `<div class="bg-image"></div>` only with absolute positioning?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4w48urft/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, just add `position: relative` to `.main-box`

https://jsfiddle.net/sp2mjbur/